# View installed packages in a docker container

Tags: docker

There are containers raised in Docker. Containers run applications such as nginx, apache, etc.

How can I list the installed versions of those applications in each container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `docker container inspect <container-id>`

```
$ docker container inspect --format '{{.Config.Env}}' cfa 
[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin NGINX_VERSION=1.17.7 NJS_VERSION=0.3.7 PKG_RELEASE=1~buster]
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want? Check all versions? List all packages?

Type this inside container shell to check **nginx**/**apache** version:

```sh
$ nginx -v #=> Nginx
$ httpd -v #=> Apache
```

To connect to container bash (for example [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine)):

```
$ docker container run -it alpine /bin/sh
```